# How do I define the items in the menu row or even better have the default format menu item appear in the toolbar?

Tags: menu, format, tinymce, toolbar

I changed menu to this:

```
menubar: 'format table tools help'
```

But what appears in the menu in my editor is just format. Table, tools, and help don't appear. Why is that so?

Also, if I want to get rid of the menubar I know I need to set

```
menubar: false
```

but is there a way of getting that nice `format` item from the menubar into the toolbar?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the item to appear in the menu you also need to load the plugin itself.  If (for example) you don't load the `help` plugin TinyMCE won't show a Help menu because the underlying functionality is not loaded.

> is there a way of getting that nice format item from the menubar into
> the toolbar?

The short answer is "no".  A menu item and a toolbar item are different.  That being said, many of the capabilities exposed via the Menubar can also be exposed via the Toolbar.

Here is an example of loading both the Help menu option as well as the toolbar button.

https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/S5haab

Comment: Thanks. That was useful. I would, then, like to add certain items from Format into the toolbar (and maybe consolidate them later on). Where can I find a list? For example, font size and other common ones inside that Format menu item?

Comment: My additional comment seems to have disappeared. In the plugins, why are they grouped as a set of three space-delimited strings in the array? Thanks.

Comment: TinyMCE will accept an array of stings (or just one string) for the list.  Either is acceptable and allowed for backwards compatibility with older TinyMCE releases.

Comment: Thanks. Can you point me to some doc page where I can find a list of items I can add to the toolbar? For example, if I want to get rid of the menubar yet keep font size on the toolbar as a separate item, what would that be called?